# Discount Codes Not Working After Update (Magento 2.2.9)

Tags: magento2, discount, magento2.2.9

After an otherwise successful update to Magento 2.2.9, the discount code functionality has stopped working.

When I try to apply it on the Cart page, nothing happens. When I try it on the Payment Method step of checkout, I receive a "Could not apply coupon code" error.

Does anyone know what could be causing this, or how to investigate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formkeys were added to the coupon form in 2.2.9 (as well as forgot password form for customers).

In your template `Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/coupon.phtml`, inside the `<form>` element you'll need to add:

```
<?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

Comment: Hmm, this was a promising answer, but doesn't seem to have helped.

Comment: I think that this solution, in tandem with updating an extension, ultimately fixed my issue. Thank you!

Comment: @brackfost That would have been my next suggestion; to check for any third party modules that could be breaking it. We had a normal coupon flow & the formkey was the solution in the end, where we saw the cart page just refreshing.